# rms measured from STM32F407 is varying slow after changing input

Tags: rms, stm32f4-discovery

I am using STM32F407 microcontroller with Simulink. After taking the input samples through ADC i convert it to voltage and then measure the rms value using RMS block in DSP system toolbox. I have used running rms for rms computation. I am getting the measured rms value at the LCD but when i remove the input i.e. 0V, the LCD or even LEDs do not respond instantaneously rather the value starts decreasing and gets to zero in almost minutes i.e. 4-5 min from 115V. I want help to understand what is the reason for this slow response in rms computation and is there any solution for it?

Comment: Removing an input signal from the input does not instantly mean you have applied 0V to that input.

Comment: Ok but at least it should reduce at some pretty fast rate after reducing the input, but it is taking minutes. I want it changed in milliseconds

Comment: If you open circuit the input it could take ages to settle down. If, instead, you are definitely reducing the input (and any slow moving dc effects) fairly instantaneously then no problem.

Comment: Can u please tell me the reason for that i.e. If you open circuit the input it could take ages to settle down

Comment: Because an input is usually high impedance and can take a long time to have all the charge removed.

Answer (score 1):

Running rms calculates the value of all samples from the time the rms block was reset. So if you remove the input the STM32F407 should immediately start sending zeros, but the rms value calculated is the average of those zeros plus *all the previous readings*.

If you want the rms value to change in milliseconds then you need to reset the rms block after some milliseconds. To get an accurate measurement of mains voltage the block period should be a multiple of one AC cycle. One way to do this might be to detect zero crossings and use this signal to reset the rms block.

Comment: I have used this reset option using an impulse block which gives rising edge impulse after every 20 ms i.e. the period of my AC sine wave, but i haven't used the zero crossings method.